Data.table - how to format multiple existing columns
I have a data.table object in 'r' with multiple columns that I would like to format as a numeric with 2 decimal points - I was looking at using functions like :-
format(round(col1, 2), 2)

Something along these lines :-
char_cols <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
test_dt[, (char_cols) := lapply(.SD, format(round('xxxx, 2), 2)), .SDcols = char_cols]

Not sure if this is acceptable :-
test_dt[, (char_cols) := lapply(.SD, f(x) format(round(x), 2), 2)), .SDcols = char_cols]

Don't know how to use the parameter for the function. I know how to use it in the context of dataframe but kind of got stuck here with data.table.
Please advise. Thanks in advance.
Best regards
Deepak

\(x)  not f(x).

I don't understand the question but I can comment on a few things : you have a digits arg in format, it's bad practice (though widespread) to use round() for formatting purpose, see also ?sprintf (go first to the examples, the detailed doc is dense). you can also use options(digits=) to   change the way numbers are printed, you could build a function to set those options temporarily, or use the withr package. I think we should avoid modifying data for formatting purposes in general.

(unless we really have no acceptable solution through format() / print() methods or options)

Ah, sure enough print.data.table passes its ... to format.data.table which forwards them to format() for individual cols as far as I can tell, so basically you just need this : print(data.table::data.table(a=1.11111111), digits = 2)

Thanks for pointing me to the 'sprintf' function - didn't realize that it existed - haven't coded in C in over 20 years. Great. Thanks. BTW, how do I accept your answer?

Also, how do I do that for a number of variables in a loop?

I tried to use the sprintf() function with the lapply function first converting the data.table to the dataframe but it converted the fields to character rather than retaining them to numbers. For the data.table, it only retained these columns that I changed the format for, all the other columns were lost. Is there no way to format a number to a specific format and retain them as numeric values?
